# RSpec failing to show message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm testing in RSpec and can't figure out why I keep getting this error message:

```
 → rspec
```

> .F.F.[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
>   ...

```
Failures:

1) An event is not free if the price is positive
 Failure/Error: expect(event).not_to be_free
   expected free? to return false, got true
 # ./spec/models/event_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

> 2) Viewing an individual event shows the price for an event with a non-zero price
>        Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text("$10.00")
>          expected to find text "$10.00" in "BugSmash A fun evening of bug smashing! When 2014->01-16 15:42:35 UTC Where Denver Price Free All Events"
>        # ./spec/features/show_event_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in '

```
  Finished in 0.39876 seconds
  8 examples, 2 failures

  Failed examples:

 rspec ./spec/models/event_spec.rb:10 # An event is not free if the price is positive
 rspec ./spec/features/show_event_spec.rb:16 # Viewing an individual event shows the price      for an event with a non-zero price

 Randomized with seed 37892
```

Here is event_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "An event" do
  it "is free if the price is $0" do
    event = Event.new(price: 0)

    expect(event).to be_free
  end

  it "is not free if the price is positive" do
    event = Event.new(price: 10)

    expect(event).not_to be_free    
  end
end
```

and here is my show_event_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Viewing an individual event" do

  it "shows the event's details" do
    event = Event.create(event_attributes)

    visit event_path(event)

    expect(page).to have_text(event.name)
    expect(page).to have_text(event.location)
    expect(page).to have_text(event.description)
    expect(page).to have_text(event.start_at)
  end

  it "shows the price for an event with a non-zero price" do
    event = Event.create(event_attributes(price: 10.00))

    visit event_path(event)

    expect(page).to have_text("$10.00")
  end

  it "shows 'Free' for an event with a zero price" do
    event = Event.create(event_attributes(price: 0.00))

    visit event_path(event)

    expect(page).to have_text("Free")
  end
end
```

here is the event.rb:

```
  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
def free?
   price.blank? || price.zero?
end
  end
```

index.html.erb:

```
  <h1><%= pluralize(@events.size, 'Event') %></h1>

 <% @events.each do |event| %>
  <article>
   <header>
   <h2><%= link_to event.name, event %></h2>
   </header>
   <p>
  <%= truncate(event.description, length: 35, separator: ' ') %>
  </p>
   <table>
  <tr>
    <th>When:</th>
    <td><%= event.start_at %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Where:</th>
    <td><%= event.location %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <th>Price:</th>
       <td><%= number_to_currency(event.price) %></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
   </article>
 <% end %>
```

and show.html.erb:

```
 <article>
 <header>
<h1><%= @event.name %></h1>
</header>
<p>
<%= @event.description %>
</p>
<h3>When</h3>
<p>
<%= @event.start_at %>
</p>
<h3>Where</h3>
<p>
<%= @event.location %>
</p>
<h3>Price</h3>
<p>
 <%= format_price(@event) %>
</p>
</article>

<%= link_to "All Events", events_path %>
```

Comment: Show us the code of your model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check the price, a comparison of some kind is needed in the `#free?` method.

You can check for blank and 0 at the same time by converting to an integer and then comparing with zero.

```
def free?
  price.to_i.zero?
end
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
def free?
    true
end
```

Your method always returns true. I suggest you should write something like

```
def free?
    price == 0
end
```

As long as you don't have negative prices:)

Comment: Changed it and got more error messages. What you said makes sense though.

Comment: I tried price.blank? || price.zero? too... getting same error messages.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I'm not familiar with Rails. So I might be missing something here.

Your `event.rb` doesn't do any check. Please adjust it.

To give an example of how the code should look like:

```
class Event 
    def free?(int)
        int > 0
    end
end

x = Event.new
p x.free?(1).inspect # true
p x.free?(0).inspect # false
```

I think that's all there is to it.

Comment: `int > 0` will return `true` or `false`, ternary operator is  unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

```
class Event
  def free?
    price > 0
  end
end
```

But you have to be sure that the price is stored as integer in the database, not as a string or null. So make it a 0 as default price for events in the table. And force validation.